# How to pass parameters to a python script that will be run using a bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script which actually does some test and write the results to a file. This python file must be provided with list of arguments:

```
myPc@myPc:~/Desktop/tests$ ./testScript.py --final fromTo 201983:310029 -o res.txt
```

Every time I need new result for different ranges I have to do them manually so I decided to write a bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=`wc -l < inFile.txt`
declare -a periods
declare -i index=0

echo "Number of Periods is: $a"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
periods[$index]=$line
((index += 1))
done < "inFile.txt"


for ((i=0;i<1300;i++)); do
f1=${period[$i]}
f2=${period[$i+1]}
python testScript.py "--final fromTo $f1:$f2 -o res$i.txt"
done

#END
```

The ranges are already in a text file so I am reading them and store them into an array.

I wish to use the bash to re-run every time the python script with different ranges until all ranges are covered and all results for all ranges are wrote in a separate file. But I am facing an issue that the parameters I try to pass to python are not even passed. I don't really understand what is the issue in here.

```
    "--final fromTo $f1:$f2 -o res$i.txt"
```

this is the parameter I want to pass and once finished I will pass new params and run it again but it seems it is not even looking at them

Comment: You might need to also show how your python script handles the parameters? Your working example has a different parameter syntax than your not working one it seems. But i have no idea if your bash is correct, so just a guess :)

Comment: I have edit the parameter I am working on two different files and copied the second file instead of the one I asked... Sorry for that

Comment: Remove the quotes and it should work. The script obviously expects multiple words, and by quoting, you are passing a single word (a single argument with spaces).

Comment: Print the args in your python script, then debug: print sys.argv[1:]

Comment: Even if I try to write python testScript.py "--final fromTo 121212:121233 -o res.txt" and remove the loop to do one test , it will not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes around arguments:

```
python testScript.py "--final fromTo $f1:$f2 -o res$i.txt"
```

are causing the complete string to be passed as **a single argument with spaces** to Python script.

By removing quotes (or at least putting them around words):

```
python testScript.py --final fromTo "$f1:$f2" -o "res$i.txt"
```

the `sys.argv` will be populated correctly, and your argument parser will work (note that [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) uses `sys.argv` by default).

---

As a little proof, `test.py` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Now try:

```
$ python test.py 1 2 3
['test.py', '1', '2', '3']

$ python test.py "1 2 3"
['test.py', '1 2 3']
```

---

Unrelated to this, but for completeness' sake, your `bash` script can be  simplified by using the [`mapfile`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) built-in (aka `readarray`, available since `bash` 4.0):

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t periods <inFile.txt

cnt="${#periods[@]}"
echo "Number of Periods is: $cnt"

for ((i=0; i<cnt; i++)); do
    python testScript.py --final fromTo "${period[$i]}:${period[$i+1]}" -o "res$i.txt"
done
```

Comment: I have done exactly the same and it worked but instead of reading from the array I hard coded the interval and thanks a lot it worked. I figured out that the problem is reading them from a file. I checked the file there are no spaces and no extrac charecters, the only thing is i have 1306 number in the file and each is a separete line. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Try with `mapfile -t`, to remove trailing newlines.

Comment: I get the output overlapping when I try to print it.. like: 
 -o res1291.txt400000000010336000000000 it is like it starts writing or it changes the order of the argument after adding the interval from the array

Comment: @ushehri, your intervals overlap (or rather, touch) because you're incrementing index by only one (`i++`). You can try with `i+=2`. Maybe I don't understand your follow-up question, in that case, please update the original question with sample input and expected output.

Comment: I may used wrong words to explain the issue. I did print the recived args by the python file and there were \r\n at the end of each interval limits. So the array has every period like 1000040\r\n. Any way to trim these? I think that will solve every thing

Comment: @ushehri, see my comment above - try with "mapfile -t".

Comment: I solved the issue Using ${period[$i]::-1}:${period[$i+1]::-1} worked 100%.

Comment: @ushehri, oh, I see now the problem you had was probably due to DOS/Windows newlines (`\r\n`). Linux/Unix tools usually work with `\n` only. You can strip all `\r` with tools like `dos2unix`, or with `sed 's/\r//g' file`, or `tr -d '\r' file`..

Answer (score 1):

What you type on the commandline is six strings: "./testScript.py" "--final" "fromTo" "201983:310029" "-o" "res.txt"

```
$ cat args.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print sys.argv
$ ./args.py --final fromTo 201983:310029 -o res.txt
['./args.py', '--final', 'fromTo', '201983:310029', '-o', 'res.txt']
```

When you put double-quotes around the last four strings, you force your shell to treat them as a single string.  Not Python's fault.

```
./args.py "--final fromTo 201983:310029 -o res.txt"
['./args.py', '--final fromTo 201983:310029 -o res.txt']
```

Just put the quotes around the items that must be handled as single strings:

```
$ f1=201983; f2=310029; i=1
$ ./args.py --final fromTo "$f1:$f2" -o "res$i.txt"
['./args.py', '--final', 'fromTo', '201983:310029', '-o', 'res1.txt']
```